# Inheritance in both class and nested class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have a base class representing a tree.

```
class BaseTree
{
protected:
    class Node
    {
    public:
        Node* left()
        { return children[0]; }

        Node* right()
        { return children[1]; }

    protected:
        std::vector<Node*> children;
    };

    Node* root;

public:
    Node* get_root()
    { return root; }
};
```

I need to create another class `DerivedTree` that inherits from `BaseTree`, and inside `DerivedTree` I want to create a nested class `DerivedTree::Node` that inherits from `BaseTree::Node`.

Somthing like this:

```
class DerivedTree : public BaseTree
{
protected:
    class Node : public BaseTree::Node
    {
    public:
        Node* third_node()
        { return (Node*)children[2]; }
    };
};

int main()
{
    DerivedTree* tree = new DerivedTree();
    tree->get_root()->third_node(); // ERROR: ‘class BaseTree::Node’ has no member named ‘third_node’
}
```

The problem is that, in `DerivedTree` and `DerivedTree::Node` the return type of the inherited member functions and the inherited variable `root` will be `BaseTree::Node*`.

Is there a way to make the return type in `DerivedTree`, `DerivedTree::Node` instead of `BaseTree::Node`?

Comment: Is this meant to be used polymorphically? If it isn't then what you have should work.

Comment: @imreal I've added a few lines showing what I'm trying to do, and what error I'm getting.

Comment: If you make the `get_root` function virtual, you can override it and make the return type co-variant.

Comment: The method `third_node` implies the derived type. If you know it has that type you might just as well cast it. `static_cast<DerivedTree::Node>(tree->get_root())->third_node();`

Comment: @imreal: I was looking for something without casting, since `DerivedTree::Node` is `protected`

Comment: @Gaith - You have to cast, but you can do it inside an overriden function, like I proposed.

Comment: @StoryTeller: I was looking for a solution that doesn't require casting in every function of each derived class. But that will work for now.